# laravel get result for database with count

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I'am looking for get result of a query and return data and count of result:

```
$res = $this->model
                ->with('', '', '', '', '')
                ->join('')
                ->join('')->get();
```

for exemple I want the result and count of result in this $res.

Comment: Have you tried `count($res);` ?

Comment: I want send data to front with result and count of result in the same eloquent request

Answer (score 0):

You can count the result of the query by using the `count` method provided by the [Collection](https://laravel.com/api/4.2/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Collection.html) instance:

```
$result = $this->model
            ->with('', '', '', '', '')
            ->join('')
            ->join('')->get();
$countResults = $result->count();
```

Or you can just use the native PHP function [`count()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.count.php):

```
$countResults = count($result);
```

Comment: I want in this action in controller return $res with the records of query and count.

Comment: As a JSON response?